# Group isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Is a group with $9$ elements such that all elements (excepted the natural element) are of order $3$ is [isomorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism) to $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ ?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, it's a good question that could  make a link to a characterization of groups of order 9, that is, $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AaronMaroja I'd assume you know "This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level" is a close reason and lack of following  general source of discontent about questions.

Comment: @quid I kind of understand. Just don't agree much. It could definitly be improved.

Comment: @AaronMaroja I see. To be clear, I have nothing much against the q; I didn't vtc even though I could.

Comment: I don't understand all these downvotes too. I just asked a simple question, how could it miss any context ? it's complicate to be more clear... anyways !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: since a group of order $p^2$ ($p$ prime) is abelian, we can use the structure theorem for finite abelian groups. A group of order $9$ is either cyclic, isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/9\mathbf Z$ or isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z $ .

Answer (score 2):

If a group $G$ has order $9$ and is not cyclic then, by Lagrange's theorem all of its elements $\neq e$ are fo order $3$. Now take $\alpha \in G$ and $\beta \in G - \langle\alpha\rangle$. Then we would have $$G = \{e, \alpha, \alpha^2,\beta,\alpha\beta,\alpha^2\beta,\beta^2,\alpha\beta^2,\alpha^2\beta^2\}$$

Then

$$\begin{cases}|G| = 9\\G=\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle\\\alpha^3=e\\\beta^3=e\end{cases}$$

Find the product $\beta\alpha$.

And work on the cases $\beta\alpha= \alpha\beta$ (take $G = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$), $\beta\alpha = \alpha^2\beta$, $\beta\alpha = \alpha\beta^2$ and $\beta\alpha^2\beta^2$, there is a contradiction for the last three cases.

Case $\beta\alpha = \alpha^2\beta^2$

$$(\alpha\beta)^2 = \alpha\beta\alpha\beta = \alpha \alpha^2\beta ^2\beta = e$$

Comment: What is the contradiction ? I don't understand ! The answer of Bernard is wrong ?

Comment: The other two you need a theorem. No, it's correct, how to get there is what I'm showing.